# Can't access vue-resource's $http methods from components in 2.0RC

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having trouble getting `vue-resource` working within `.vue` components in 2.0RC. It was working fine in 1.x but now the $http method appears to be missing when accessing `this` from within a component method.

I am using webpack and my `app.es6` file looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Login from './Login.vue'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        { path: '/login', component: Login }
    ]
})

const App = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el: "#vue-app",
    template: '<div><router-view></router-view></div>',
    created: function(){
        console.log('data this: ', this.$http()) //this $http.get() works
    }

})
```

My Login.vue looks like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Log In</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit()">Access</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
    export default {
        methods: {
            submit: function () {
                console.log('Login this.$http()', this.$http.get) //this $http.get() does not work
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Some theories are:

1. 2.0 broke things somehow but the vue-resource docs haven't been updated yet.
2. It has something to do with changing from `Vue.extend(...) and Vue.start(...)` in version 1 to the `new Vue()` syntax I'm using now.
3. I need to do something differently using the new `vue-router` syntax.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about using events from the child and handle it in the parent ??

Comment: Not a bad workaround, thanks, but I'm building a fairly complex app and this is only one of many places I'm using `vue-resource`. Moving all that logic into the parent from other sub-components would be pretty awkward.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, however I already have it aliased properly in webpack. I do however `import Vue from 'vue'` in a couple different files. I'm wondering if it's a duplicate. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm importing Vue in couple of other files without problems at this point, so maybe it's a different issue? You might try digging around in webpack's build file to see what is being referenced by each of those import statements. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got an [answer over on the Vue Help forum](http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/4917/can-t-access-vue-resource-s-http-from-components-in-2-0rc/7). The issue arose because I was using the standalone version of Vue but not fully aliasing it in Webpack, so Webpack was loading two different versions.

User LinusBorg answered:

> You require the standalone build, but webpack is also loading the
>   runtime-only build, so you end up with two versions of Vue in your
>   project - one has vue-resource, the other doesn't.
>
> If you want to keep the standalone build, you have to add an alias to
>   your webpack config: `vue: 'vue/dist/vue'`

Just in case anyone else has this problem and is as generally bewildered by webpack as I am, to be slightly more explicit:

Webpack was loading two different versions of vue.js, one from my in-file `import` statements, one from the webpack `*.vue` module loaders. The exact way I fixed it was to add the following to my `webpack-config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'}
},
```

Within my app.es6 file I also had to change back the import Vue from `'vue/dist/vue.js'` to import Vue from `'vue'`.